# Toshiba Satellite L745D - internal mic not working

Tags: 11.10, microphone, alsa, toshiba-satellite

I have a Toshiba L745D (AMD A6-3400M). I cannot get my internal mic to work.

My sound card: Conexant CX20585

I've tried this:

echo "options snd-hda-intel model=thinkpad" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

echo "options snd-hda-intel model=ideapad" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

echo "options snd-hda-intel model=asus" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

...but that didn't work either. Apparently that works for different notebook models with the same sound card. I also tried muting the right mic channel; that also worked for someone on a different model.

Here is my ALSA information:

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=6b57a7faecf5525ccb5212a6f60ee9d1bc792838

Any solutions out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further research, people with Windows 7 have also been experiencing this bug also with the default install; I reinstalled Windows 7 and used the default sound card drivers instead of the official Conexant drivers and that's why I think my mic worked in Windows 7.

If you have 'Fast Boot' enabled in the BIOS Ubuntu will not recognize the microphone. Here is my ALSA information after I switched back to 'Normal Boot':

http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=0e81ce3afc0effc162ae19c608137bd5969a0f44

And the good news is that my internal microphone is now working, but I had to reinstall Ubuntu to get my microphone working unfortunately.